# Gnome-session-flashback minimal installation

Tags: ubuntu-minimal

I installed 16.04 via MINI.iso with just the standard system utilities. I am hoping to have gnome-session-flashback as the sole DE. After installation and reboot it doesn't load to any display manager.

Tried lightdm but it won't let me login. I then tried gdm but it didn't work either. Still stuck at the command line. Please, what am I missing? Thanks.